# Duda sobre las cookies y la políticas al crear web

Tags: html, wordpress, cookies

Hola buenas tenia una duda y es que empezado hacer una web personal para vender webs y darme a conocer, la cuestión es que no es mi primera web. Llevo unas cuantas creadas pero todas han sido con Wordpress, esta es la primera que creo con programación. Ya tengo la web subida en netlify con el dominio comprado y mi duda es... Estado viendo que mi pagina web no tiene cookies y me extraña mucho porque antes con Wordpress en cualquier web tenia que poner la política de cookies porque todas tenían al menos 1.

Mi pregunta es como se generan las cookies y si en mi caso haría falta poner la normativa... ya que me parece muy raro que no tenga ninguna la verdad.

Y la segunda pregunta que tenia es si alguien sabe un poco las políticas que tendría que poner en mi web al dedicarme a la venta de webs.

Perdonen por si son preguntas muy básicas pero acabo de empezar y me pilla un poco esto de nuevo, Gracias.

Comment: En mis webs que no tengo cookies también incluyo una política de cookies, pero sin el aviso emergente, tan solo en un enlace junto con el otro enlace al aviso legal en alguna parte de mi web, y tan solo pongo 3 párrafos, a saber: *1) Nuestra política de cookies es no utilizar ninguna cookie*, 2) *Nos reservamos el derecho a modificar esta política para adaptarla a las novedades que surjan o se publiquen, así como a efectuar las modificaciones oportunas de acuerdo con las modificaciones realizadas en el código de este sitio.* y

Comment: 3) *Como usuario ha de leer atentamente la presente política de cookies en cada una de las ocasiones en que se proponga utilizar este sitio web, ya que ésta puede tener modificaciones y por lo tanto queda sujeto y tendrá que obedecer a lo expresado en la misma.* , y con eso le paso la pelota al visitante si nunca me da por cambiar la política.

Answer (score 0):

Las cokies sirven para guardan un archivo en el ordenador del usuario, este archivo se compone de variables, de esta manera puedes almacenar variables en el ordenador del usuario, de esta manera aunque este apague el ordenador tu web podrá usar una configuración específica para ese usuario, por ejemplo YouTube usa cookies para almacenar que estás usando el tema oscuro, así al iniciar el ordenador de nuevo la web seguirá teniendo esa apariencia, también se utiliza mucho para los sistemas de login.

Para hacer una cookie en javascript debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
document.cookie = 'MiCookie=HOLA';
```

Así se hace una cookie llamada MiCookie con el valor HOLA
Pero esta cookie desaparece al cerrar el navegador puesto que caduca en la session
Para hacer que tu cookie caduque más tarde deberás especificarlo.

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Fri, 22 Apr 2022 12:00:00 UTC";
```

En este caso la cookie caducaría el 22 de abril.

En cuanto al aviso, si tu web usa cookies (almenos en la unión europea) estás obligado a avisar de esto, se prevé que para un futuro no haga falta avisar si son cookies esenciales para el funcionamiento de la web.

En este enlace se explica mejor: [Política de Cookies](https://www.ensalza.com/blog/politica-de-cookies/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad que estado mirando y no es tan complicado como parece el problema es que mi web no tiene cookies de momento... Pero tengo una duda y es que a la hora de comprar un servicio en mi tienda, se les redirige a STRIPE que es una plataforma de pagos, y esta web si que hace uso de cookies. No se si por enviar a los clientes a otra web con cookies ya tendría que poner el aviso... Pero bueno